# Migration Data between two SQL Server databases

Tags: sql-server, data-migration, data-synchronization

I have a database called DB1 which installed in my local server with a desktop application and I have DB2 which contains some tables from DB1 (theses tables are the same of the related ones in the DB). So DB2 doesn't contain the full count of tables of DB1 but the structure of tables is the same. DB2 installed in cloud (hosted) with MVC application.

So my question is, how can I synchronize data between the 2 databases. Anyone can say what they thinks about that.

Note: All Databases are SQL Server DBs

Comment: How often do you want to synchronize? do you want synchronization in the same transaction? What database is the source/target?

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts  thanks for reply . I want to sync at the end of the day . both data bases can be source and target because some data inserted into db1 by the desktop app and some data inserted to db2 by the MVC app and the managers of the company wants all new data in each db reflects and appears in the other db

Comment: I think you cannot use any given mechanisms as there lies always a lot of buisness logic in synchronizing multi-master databases. Imagine the following scenario: User 1 changes the phone number of an address from 12345 to 54321 on DB1, User 2 changes 1 hour later the email of the same address from foo@tempuri.org to bar@tempuri.org. If you have a last-wins strategy, this conflict is resolves by updating the address in DB1 by overwriting it with the values of the address in DB2, resulting in the change of user 1 to be undone. You could track each change per column, but that's more work to sync.